# What is "tent canvas"?

Tags: word-meaning

What is "tent canvas" in the text below?

> He established Levi Strauss & Company in 1850 to sell pants made of tent canvas to gold miners. He eventually switched to denim cloth and made the work pants that became known as blue jeans or "Levi's."

Could you, please, give detailed explanation about the words:

1. tent - the meaning in original text
2. canvas - in other words separately
3. tent canvas - what these words mean in the original text together.

I ask it because in our language is said that Levi used canvas cloth of sails of ships to make pants. I don't understand why in original text the word "tent" is used because "tent", as I know, is a small portable tourist house made of durable fabric.

Comment: Sleeping tents are used by **campers** (or refugees) not **tourists** unless they are so-called **eco-tourists** who stay outdoors in a wilderness setting.  Tourists typically stay in a hotel or B&B.

Comment: I expect that, at that time, "tent" canvas and "sail" canvas were more or less the same thing.  Canvas has many uses.

Comment: "Tent coverings, as well as the sails of ships, are now made in the United States almost exclusively of cotton. The small quantity of linen canvas used is of foreign production, and, paying a duty, costs in the market about 10 per cent. more than cotton duck of a corresponding grade." p. 412 of *History of the American Ambulance Established in Paris During the Siege of 1870-1871, Together with the Details of Its Methods and Its Works* – Thomas Wiltberger Evans, Edward A. Crane, John Swinburne, William E. Johnston (London 1873).

Comment: Tourists may stay in a tent too. When I was a kid we always went a tourists to France and stayed in tents.

Answer (score 4):

**tent canvas** is an example of a **noun adjunct**, which means using one noun to modify another noun, like "horse race" (a race, of horses) or "chicken soup" (soup, made of chicken).

In this case, the word *tent* is modifying the word *canvas*, so that the entire noun phrase means "canvas, of the kind used for tents".

Answer (score 3):

A "tent" is a portable shelter made of some kind of cloth stretched over a frame or poles. Canvas is a heavy, densely-woven cloth. In modern America, at least, tents are usually made of canvas. Canvas is also used to make sails for ships.

So Levis made pants out of the sort of material normally used to make tents.